# PostgreSQL performance on polygon vs circle geofence lookup

Tags: postgresql, indexing, polygon, postgis, geofencing

I have to work with Postgres and fairly new to SQL database. I have to implement a geofence database that stores all the points of the fences either polygon or circle. I have found that Postgres has a geometry functiono called circle(polygon) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/functions-geometry.html

Ques1) Since logically it seems that looking up if a point is within a set of geofences of type polygon is computationally heavier as opposed to circle ones.Is it better to have an extra column that have precomputated bounding circle of those polygons. Any suggestions ?

Also feel free to throw in any advice for making geofence database like is there a need to use POSTGIS.

Comment: You use the 8.3-manual, are you sure about this version? It's old and unsupported. Do you yourself a favor and use a recent version of PostgreSQL.

Comment: Performance depends on too many factors, such as the number of rows, presence of index, type of spatial operators, complexity of geometries, etc.

Comment: Personally, I'd use PostGIS. Many functions (like st_contains) automatically calculate the bounding box of polygons to speed up query performance, so you don't need to worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

A circle cannot exclusively contain a polygon. Consider two adjacent polygons enclosed in a circle - there will be an overlap of the two circles, creating an ambiguity in the region of overlap.